# Page number always centered in automatically generated TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I have a setup where my page number is always on the bottom right side on the page, I do this with:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
```

However, when I insert

```
\tableofcontents
```

, the page number on the first page of the TOC is in the middle, but on the second page, it's on the right again.
Is there any way to bring the first page number to the right as well?

Comment: redefine the plain page style, see the fancyhdr documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been most helpful if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that showed your problem.

In the book/report classes the ToC is typeset as a `\chapter*` whereby the page number on the ToC first page is set middle bottom. You can define and use a specific pagestyle for the first page of a ToC like this.

```
% tocpagenumprob.tex  SE 642084

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{rightfoot}{%
\fancyhead{}%
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{rightfoot}}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{first}
\lipsum[3-4]

\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}

\chapter{Second}
\section{second}

\end{document}
```

It will, of course, not match with `\chapter` page styles but if that is what you want to introduce in your document, so be it. Anyway, how did you change the pagenumbering layout of `\chapter`s?

All the above is predicated on you having `\chapter`s. If that is not the case then perhaps the above MWE will help you with your particular problem. --- GOM